# What abilities allow you to break control impairing effects and other conditions?

Tags: diablo-iii

Occasionally, I've encountered opponents with the "Jailer" affix, and some bosses seem to have attacks that hold you still (though you aren't frozen). I've discovered the Wizard's [Mirror Image](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/mirror-image), if cast while rooted or frozen, will allow you to escape sometimes, and a message will pop up that says "Broke Root!" or "Broke Freeze!"

This can often be the difference between life and death, so - what other abilities (for any class) allow you to break root?

Comment: Consider rewording "condition" to "status effect".  I think that is the more general terminology.  My opinion...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Monk: **Serenity**

> You are enveloped in a protective shield that absorbs all incoming
>   damage for 3 seconds and grants immunity to all control impairing
>   effects (4 seconds with Ascension rune).

Witch Doctor: **Spirit Walk**

> Leave your physical body and enter the spirit realm for 2 seconds.
>   While in the spirit realm, your movement is unhindered.
>
> Your link to the spirit realm will end if your physical body sustains
>   50% of your maximum Life in damage.

Demon Hunter: **Smokescreen**

> Vanish behind a wall of smoke, becoming momentarily invisible for 1
>   second (without Lingering Fog rune, 1.5 with).

Wizard: **Mirror Image**

> Summon 2 illusionary duplicates of yourself that last for 7 seconds
>   and have 25% of your Life. The images may cast some of the same spells
>   as you, but those spells deal no damage.

Wizard: **Teleport with Fracture**

> Normally you can teleport when you are Jailed, but you will still be jailed after Teleporting. With the Fracture rune the Teleport will  function like using Mirror Images, breaking the jail. Teleport will not however work while Frozen, like Mirror Images will,b ecause for the Images to spawn you need to Teleport first.

Barbarian: **Furious Charge**

> Rush forward knocking back enemies and inflicting
>   195% weapon damage to enemies along the path of 
>   the charge.

Barbarian: **Wrath of the Berserker**

> Enter a berserker rage which raises several attributes for 15 seconds.

And related to using abilites while supressed, the Wizard can activate Diamond Skin even under CC.

Comment: You can use it while stunned as well.

Comment: ...I mentioned a Wizard ability *in the question!*

Comment: Brainfart :) I actually play a Wizard on Hell at the moment but have never tested Mirror Image.

Comment: Wrath of the Berserker also breaks CC and makes you immune for the duration.

Comment: The Wizard's Teleport also lets you break root (and possibly snare), but not freeze.

Comment: DH: vault can be used to break root. Smoke screen breaks fear.

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer for the last patch ? :)

Answer (score 3):

The Witch Doctor has **Spirit Walk**. I've only used it to break freeze, though.

Comment: it breaks EVERYTHING. its awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Demon Hunter has Smoke Screen, allowing to vanish behind a wall of smoke, becoming momentarily invisible. It works very well for escaping most enemy traps.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for the Jailed effect, the Monk's **Dashing Strike** ability allows you to move a short distance while within the jail.

You're still stuck in the jail, though.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the skills listed above, there are the Legendary Boots called [Ice Climbers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ice-climbers) that allow you to completely ignore all freeze and immobilizing effects. They're a good alternative if you don't want to use a skill slot for this effect.