# How can I break a freezing spell

Tags: diablo-iii

In Act IV and end of III (normal) I've started encountering elite mobs that are "frozen" and release some king of "frozen orbs" that freeze me. Is there a way to avoid being frozen other then moving away?

- Is there a way to resist freezing or increase my resistance?
- Is there a way to break a freezing spell that was cast on me?

p.s.
I'm playing as a wizard, but info for all classes is appreciated.

Comment: +1 I've also been wondering this, as Uzual kept pwning me by freezing me in place and then turning me into Monk pâté.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Is there a way to resist freezing or increase my resistance?*

There is a way to reduce the duration by equipping "reduce control impairing effects by xx%" gear. As for resistance, AFAIK there is nothing to resist them.

*Is there a way to break a freezing spell that was cast on me?*

[List of skills](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67379/what-abilities-allow-you-to-break-control-impairing-effects-and-other-conditions)

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak for the Barbarian but with [Wrath of the Berserker](http://www.diablowiki.net/Wrath_of_the_Berserker) we can remove the freezing and are immune to any CC effect for the duration of the spell.
There might be similar spells for other classes.

I don't think there is an attribute similar to [Cannot be frozen](http://www.diablowiki.com/Cannot_be_Frozen_%28Diablo_II%29). Also I haven't seen myself resisting a freezing so far.

Comment: Also note, that the similarly powerful Archon form of the Wizard does not prevent freezing.

Comment: The description you linked does not state any removing of freezing or immunity thereto. Where did you get that information?

Comment: Extensive personal experience.

Comment: According to forum reports, it makes the barb indeed immune to fear and stun, but only for a few seconds. "For the duration of the spell" part is not quite right.

Comment: I can assure you it is for the whole duration. And btw, http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/mirror-image doesn't state any of the freeing effects either.

Comment: That is really OP.. Doesn't bother me since it's Hell's minions on the sharp end of the stick, but when pvp starts, the shit's going to hit the fan. Same thing for the Mirror Image + [Illusionist](http://www.diablowiki.net/Illusionist)

Answer (score 1):

As a wizard you can break the frozen negative effect by casting mirror image (with any of the runes equiped) - this also breaks jailer as well.

I'm pretty sure teleport does the same thing, but not 100%, haven't tried it myself.

The other great thing about Mirror Image is it doesn't cost you any AP, and it gives the monsters some nice cannon fodder to go after while you gear up to beat them to a pulp.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Excellent tip about the mirror image freeing frozen or jailed wizards

Comment: Also of note, if you use the passive that resets mirror image & teleport whenever you get hit for 15% of your max health, you will be able to break the freeze/jail pretty much every time you get caught by one - you'll take one hit, reset the ability, then pop mirror image and run like hell :)

Answer (score 1):

I use Spirt Walk for my Witch Doctor to break out of frozen/jailer immediately.