# What statuses count as control-impairing effects?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just got a nice shiny new legendary gem.  [Bane of the Trapped](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bane-of-the-trapped), to be exact.  Which has, as its primary effect:

> Increase damage against enemies under the effects of control-impairing effects by X.

Obviously, it's in my best interest to ensure my enemies are under at least one of these effects at all times, for a constant boost to damage.  My question is, what statuses count as control-impairing?  I'm guessing slow does, as that's what the gem itself will give once it gets to rank 25, but until that point, I'm going to need something else to hit them with.

So what can I use to ensure this gem's damage boost gets as much uptime as possible?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67379/what-abilities-allow-you-to-break-control-impairing-effects-and-other-conditions lists three of them (Stun, Frozen, Root).  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63649/51171 has a full list.

Comment: Might be worth noting in the question that this does not apply to the current version of the game... (not off-topic, because the public test system is, well, public - but potentially confusing until 2.1 hits :-))

Comment: @SimonW 2.1 hit yesterday.  It's about as live as it can get.

Comment: @frank ah, fair enough! It hadn't hit yesterday evening, when I last played :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Control impairing effects** are also referred to as **Crowd Control**. Those include exhaustively in Diablo 3 :

- Knockback
- Stun
- Slow (Including Chill effect)
- Freeze
- Immobilize
- Fear
- Confusion
- Blind
- Taunt
- Charm
- Hex

[Source for the list](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Crowd_Control) and here is [the list of the skills that induce a control impairing effect](http://www.diablowiki.net/Crowd_Control) (*might be updated over time*)